# Javascript returning undefined on variable

Tags: javascript, variables, undefined

I have this part of code:

```
for (i = 0; i <= texte.split(';')[1].split(',').length - 1; i++) {
        cell = document.createElement("td");
        cell.setAttribute("width", "10%");
        cell.setAttribute("align", "center");
        if (texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i] != "")
            cell.onclick = function () { chgnom('1',"'" + texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i] + "'",''); };
        textnode = document.createElement("span");
        textnode.innerHTML = texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i];
        cell.appendChild(textnode);
        row.appendChild(cell);
    }
```

The call to `texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i]` in innerHTML returns 'HELLO', but the one in function return 'undefined'. Could someone help me with this?

Thank you

Comment: Could you show us a demo on http://JSFiddle.net?

Comment: your example needs to have more information in it.  IF it is underfined, you might be splitting on something which doesnt exist for example.

Comment: whats the value of texte ? and where is row variable decalred ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume `arr=texte.split(';')[1].split(',')`. When your click will be executed, `i` will be already equal to `arr.length`.`arr[arr.length]` is `undefined`,and that was what you got. Workaround could be something like a:

```
if (texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i] != ""){
    cell.onclick = (function(inner_i){
        return function () { 
            chgnom('1',"'" + texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[inner_i] + "'",''); 
        };
    })(i);
}
```

Comment: He was already using a closure, what you have posted is a closure that returns a closure. Use the terms properly, because a closure is not a function that returns a function, but a dynamically assigned function which may or may not be returned inside another function, and which in turn may or may not be a closure.

Answer (score 0):

Have you test your `texte.split(';')[1].split(",")[i]` for each loop ?
Try to put that in variable before.